# Geometry and integral laws of physics

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, math-history

Reading the English translation of Einstein's seminal paper on GR.

http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/90?ajax

This paragraph below on p78 doesn't make much sense to me.

Could you provide a second English translation or even adding math notation.

"Before Maxwell, the laws of nature with respect to their space dependence were in principle integral laws; this is to say that in elementary laws the distances between finitely distinct points did occur. Euclidean geometry is the basis for this description of nature. This geometry means originally only the essence of conclusions from geometric axioms; in this regard it has no physical content. But geometry becomes a physical science by adding the statement that two points of a "rigid" body shall have a distinct distance from each other that is independent of the position of the body. After this amendment, the theorems of this amended geometry are (in a physical sense) either factually true or not true. It is geometry in this extended sense which forms the basis of physics. Seen from this aspect, the theorems of geometry are to be looked as integral laws of physics insofar as they deal with distance of points *at a finite range*."

Specifically I do not get the points here

**integral laws; this is to say that in elementary laws the distances between finitely distinct points did occur.**

For example?

**This geometry means originally only the essence of conclusions from geometric axioms; in this regard it has no physical content**

For example?

**Seen from this aspect, the theorems of geometry are to be looked as integral laws of physics**

What is the definition of an integral law?

Comment: @daniel Thanks just added them above?

Comment: Makes sense then. Perhaps the translator has picked integral for his own taste!

Comment: Wonderful re translation. Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully my guesses were helpful but there's no way around understanding the paper in its entirety to be sure, especially about the first item. There are users here who could give an authoritative response so I'm deleting my comments and upvoting, since the question is pretty specific.

Comment: Yes very helpful!

Comment: I think Einstein is arguing not to take whatever you think as geometry for granted, most people see Geometry is the unchanging, neutral, uniform "medium" in which physics happen.  but then there are complex questions like  which geometry? There is more than just the Euclidean geometry option.
Or maybe even the medium is not unchanging, neutral of uniform making it al very complicated, what is that problem from bending space near stars in which medium do they bend?

Comment: @daniel that is why I made it a comment and did hedge myself

Comment: @Willemien:  I didn't mean to sound peremptory. Certainly your first idea is on track.

Comment: @daniel No offence taken, I  hope the question gets an answer I can learn from